# Can't connect to sphinx database

Tags: mysql, linux, database, search-engine, sphinx

actually I am new to Sphinx & I was trying all day long to follow the quick reference on their website [See over here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#quick-tour)
The problem is that I can't in a certain way access the database of sphinx via 
    `mysql -h0 -P9306`
like they've done ... I have tried every instruction on the web ... please could you help me figure this out ?
here is the error I get every time:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0' (111)
```

Comment: Is `searchd` actually running? Do you have the approriate `listen` directives in your config file, so searchd is listening where you think it should be. Do you have a firewall preventing connections?

Answer (score 0):

Quite strange ... I think your sphinx version is different from the one you're trying to follow ...

Comment: No sorry, I don't think so